# Where is my Ready/secondary instance located

Tags: instance

Our location is Active (or Primary) is easy to determine (as described in numerous places but how can we determine the geographic location of our Ready (or secondary) instance?
I've looked in the site switching information and FAQs but have come up blank.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome! ~Are you referring to B2C Commerce / Demandware instances?~ Nevermind, found the document you're referring to here: [Site Switching Overview and FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387541&type=1)